# How to divide every element in array by a certain number?

Tags: raku

I have an array:

```
my @e = <60.922    20.946     8.721     7.292     4.306     2.821     2.765     2.752     2.741     2.725>
```

I would like to divide every element in the array by the minimum, however

```
@e /= @e.min
```

produced a single element, which isn't correct.

I've read https://docs.raku.org/type/Array but I don't understand the basic elements of Raku for this.

How can I divide every item in the array by the same number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the raku [hyper](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) & [compound](https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Assignment_operators) metaoperators like this:

`@a >>/=>> @a.min`

- `>>X>>` means "apply operator `X` over all list items (with more items on the left)"
- `/=` means "assign result of divide operator `/` to replace each original left hand item"

Use `/` instead of `/=` if you want to return the list of results but leave @a unchanged functional programming style.

[Edited according to @lizmat & @Sebastian comments]

Comment: I like it  :-)   But I think `@a >>/=>> @a.min` would be more appropriate, as that would actually change the contents of the array, which is what the op indicated.

Comment: oooh - didn't know you can do that - even better!

Comment: Perhaps you can include the >>/=>> into the answer (as another option)?

Answer (score 8):

```
my @a = 2, 3, 5, 7, 10;
my $div = @a.min;
$_ /= $div for @a;
say @a;  # [1 1.5 2.5 3.5 5]
```

When you iterate over an array, you get mutable elements.

Answer (score 4):

```py
put @e.map( * / @e.min );
```

OR

```py
put @e.map: * / @e.min;
```

Sample Input:

```
my @e = <60.922  20.946  8.721  7.292  4.306  2.821  2.765  2.752  2.741  2.725>;
```

Sample Output:

```
22.356697 7.686606 3.200367 2.675963 1.580183 1.035229 1.014679 1.009908 1.005872 1
```

---

If you want to continue working with the resultant values, assign the output to a new variable.  Or overwrite the original `@e` array using the `.=` "back-assignment" operator [ short for `@e = @e.map( … )` ]. In the Raku REPL:

```perl
~$ raku
Welcome to ™ v2021.06.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2021.06.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my @e = <60.922  20.946  8.721  7.292  4.306  2.821  2.765  2.752  2.741  2.725>;
[60.922 20.946 8.721 7.292 4.306 2.821 2.765 2.752 2.741 2.725]
> @e .= map( * / @e.min );
[22.356697 7.686606 3.200367 2.675963 1.580183 1.035229 1.014679 1.009908 1.005872 1]
> put @e;
22.356697 7.686606 3.200367 2.675963 1.580183 1.035229 1.014679 1.009908 1.005872 1
>
```